# How to I find T(0,1,1)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T be a linear transformation from $R^3$ to $R$ such that $T(1,1,1) = 1$, $T(1,1,0) = 2$ and $T(1,0,0) = 3$. Find $T(0,1,1)$.
I'm trying to solve it by this way: $R1 - R3$ -> $R1$. Is it correct?
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  1&1&0&2\\
  1&0&0&3\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
=>$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&1&1&-2\\
  1&1&0&2\\
  1&0&0&3\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Comment: $T$ is _linear_. What does that mean to you?

Comment: Use matrix to solve?

Comment: What is your try. Please add you try to the question.

Comment: Matrices are part of the theory around linear transformations, yes. And this can probably be solved with matrices. But that's not what I asked you about. I did not ask what consequences "$T$ is linear" has on how one would solve the problem. That is the _next_ step. I asked what you think "linear transformation" means. Without that you can't even begin to solve this problem.

Comment: I added my try to the question.

Comment: Not even close. What does this augmented matrix that you’ve constructed represent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since
$$
(0,1,1) = (1,1,1) - (1,0,0),
$$
we have
\begin{align}
T(0,1,1) &= T((1,1,1) - (1,0,0))\\
&= T(1,1,1) - T(1,0,0)\\
&= 1 - 3\\
&= -2.
\end{align}

Comment: This is wrong. You need to take another look at $-T(1,0,0)$.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks, corrected the typo.

Comment: Actually this is **the right way** to address these plz-do-hwk-asap questions with no context: to give deliberately a wrong answer. So simple and so effective...

Comment: @Did The answer has been corrected...